# Uncompadible types: void cannot be converted to string

Tags: java, string, swing, error-handling, void

Hello fellow programmers, I need some help for an assignment text for school.

With this text I get the error message: Uncompilable source code - incompatible types: void cannot be converted to java.lang.String

My intention is that the program will take a sentence and then count the amount of vowels and consonants and show them in a dialog window.

I am very new to programming so the answer is probably very obvious for all of you, but help would be very much appreciated :D

So to be clear, my question is as follows. How can I fix the void to string error?

```
public static void main (String args[]) {

    String string1= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a sentence.");
    int count = 0;
    int vowels = 0;
    int consonants = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <string1.charAt(0); i++) {
            char ch = string1.charAt(i);
            if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || 
                            ch == 'o' || ch == 'u')
            {
                    vowels++;
            }
            else
            { 
                    consonants++;
            }
           String finished= JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have written " +vowels+ "vowels and you have written " +consonants+ "consonants");
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the error tell you?

Comment: I believe you meant `i <string1.length()`

Comment: The error should tell a line number where it's happening. Go to that line, and see what [each method returns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29), and what you try to do with it. You'll find the mistake pretty quickly.

Answer (score 2):

If you use any IDE, this line is going to complain at you

```
String finished= JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
```

Because `showMessageDialog` doesn't return anything, it's a void method, so there is no finished String to get from it, it just shows a pop-up window

Answer (score 2):

```
String finished= JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...)
```

There's your problem.

```
public static void showMessageDialog(...)
```

As you can see, the method showMessageDialog return type is void.

Remove "String finished=" and it will work.

**However**. It will not work as intended because of other errors. Inside the for loop, the condition

```
i < string1.charAt(0)
```

is wrong.

But even when you fix that, it will not work properly. You should call

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...)
```

outside of loop, so that it's displayed only once.

And even when you fix *all* those errors, it will still not work correctly, taking into account that a character can be something other than a vowel or consonant. Or that letters can be in uppercase.